# Pandas convert string to int

Tags: python, pandas, string, type-conversion

I have a large dataframe with ID numbers:

```
ID.head()
Out[64]: 
0    4806105017087
1    4806105017087
2    4806105017087
3    4901295030089
4    4901295030089
```

These are all strings at the moment.

I want to convert to `int` without using loops - for this I use `ID.astype(int)`.

The problem is that some of my lines contain dirty data which cannot be converted to `int`, for e.g.

```
ID[154382]
Out[58]: 'CN414149'
```

How can I (without using loops) remove these type of occurrences so that I can use `astype` with peace of mind?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You need add parameter `errors='coerce'` to function [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
ID = pd.to_numeric(ID, errors='coerce')
```

If `ID` is column:

```
df.ID = pd.to_numeric(df.ID, errors='coerce')
```

but non numeric are converted to `NaN`, so all values are `float`.

For `int` need convert `NaN` to some value e.g. `0` and then cast to `int`:

```
df.ID = pd.to_numeric(df.ID, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['4806105017087','4806105017087','CN414149']})
print (df)
              ID
0  4806105017087
1  4806105017087
2       CN414149

print (pd.to_numeric(df.ID, errors='coerce'))
0    4.806105e+12
1    4.806105e+12
2             NaN
Name: ID, dtype: float64

df.ID = pd.to_numeric(df.ID, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(np.int64)
print (df)
              ID
0  4806105017087
1  4806105017087
2              0
```

EDIT: If use pandas 0.25+ then is possible use [`integer_na`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df.ID = pd.to_numeric(df.ID, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
print (df)
              ID
0  4806105017087
1  4806105017087
2            NaN
```

Answer (score 7):

1. If you're here because you got

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

use `.astype('int64')` for 64-bit signed integers:

```py
df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype('int64')
```

---

If you don't want to lose the values with letters in them, use `str.replace()` with a regex pattern to remove the non-digit characters.

```py
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace('[^0-9]', '', regex=True).astype('int64')
```

Then input

```
0    4806105017087
1    4806105017087
2         CN414149
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

converts into

```
0    4806105017087
1    4806105017087
2           414149
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it Jan-2024 in the latest version of jupyter notebook by doing this.

Always use try and catch to see if its not working than what the error.
I checked the "Price" data type and previously it was "o" and now its showing "int(64)". That's what we all looking for.

```
try:
    car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.replace('[\$\,]|\.\d*', '', regex=True).astype(int)
except ValueError as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```