# Need a way to split string pandas to colums with numbers

Tags: pandas

hi i have string in one column : 
s='123. 125. 200.'
i want to split it to 3 columns(or as many numbers i have ends with .) 
To separate columns and that it will be number not string !, in every column .

Comment: You can use `str.split` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333299/splitting-a-column-by-delimiter-pandas-python). `to_numeric` can help you convert to int, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719749/pandas-convert-string-to-int).

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand, you can use:

```
s='123. 125. 200.'
pd.Series(s).str.rstrip('.').str.split('.',expand=True).apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
```

---

```
     0     1     2
0  123   125   200
```

Comment: maybe clarify that the `rstrip` will remove the last `.` and that `expand` will create new columns based on the split token (`.`)? OP asked for numbers, I think `to_numeric` would do the trick, right?